# tf.print fails in Keras with tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

The exception is

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_datatype_enum'
```

How should the `tf.print` or whatever other method be used inside the model construction for things run from keras?

Comment: Can you please show the code that raises the exception?